# Read serial data from incoming USB device on the Pico

Tags: usb, serial, pi-pico, micropython

So I am new to using the pico w and I am trying to connect a scoreboard controller device (Daktronics All Sport® 5000) that outputs real time data over serial. I have an RS323 to USB converter that is connected to the Pico via a female usb break out. The break out board is connected to the USB test pads respectively. I have tried to power the Pico with external power and read the USB with the following code:

```
from sys import stdin
from machine import Pin
import _thread, uselect
from time import sleep

led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
led.toggle()

while True:
    buffer = []
    select_result = uselect.select([stdin], [], [], 0)
    while select_result[0]:
        char = stdin.read(1)
        buffer.append(char)
        select_result = uselect.select([stdin], [], [], 0)
    
    message = "".join(buffer) if buffer != [] else None
    if message != None:
        with open("in.txt", "w") as f:
            led.toggle()
            f.write(message)
```

I believe the reason this doesn't work is because the device I am connecting is a USB device and needs to be connected to a host and the Pico is not one. With some basic research it looks like USB host support is not out yet for Micropython. Is this true? If so are there any ways around this to read the incoming serial message?

I guess simply I want to know if I can replace the USB micro on the board with a USB-A female port to make connection with the controller easier.

Comment: please add info about the scoreboard controller ... add to the post ... **do not** use a comment

Comment: Sounds like you need to connect the serial scoreboard to the Pico serial UART connections https://electrocredible.com/raspberry-pi-pico-serial-uart-micropython/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.